# UNITY JNI android plugin GetApplicationContext()

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a plugin for Unity Android using JNI. I create the .jar file with my Java code, and then .so file with the c++ bridge. Everything works fine when I call my library from Unity side. So, my problem is that in several parts of my Java code, I need to access to the context of the main activity (UnityPlayer3d). I need a pointer to this activity to call the function GetApplicationContext().

How can I obtain this pointer? I think about passing the pointer from Unity to my Java class as a parameter, but first I have to get it in Unity side.

Comment: please include any relevant code. Show us what you have tried

Comment: This is an example of a function I want to call from Unity side. The problem is that I need the context of the activity created by Unity, not the context of the object I've created in the c++ file using JNI (jobject). 

    public void StartPushNotification(){
     airpush=new Airpush(this.getApplicationContext());
     airpush.startPushNotification(false);
    }

Comment: @user1782945 have you got this done? any success in Developing this Plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to get the activity JNI style:

```
var unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
var unityActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is wrong, you don't need to pass Context pointer from Unity(C#) to Java, you can get the Context in Android Pluglin MainActivity(this is the main activity (UnityPlayer3d) you mentioned in your post) directly as follow:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this.getApplicationContext();
}
```

And then, you can operate the context to do stuff in JAVA intead of writing it in Unity(C#)
Hope it be helpful. :)